# Type mismatch. Required: Color Found: Any. How do I solve this issue?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, themes

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            CalculatorTheme {
                val viewModel = viewModel<CalculatorViewModel>()
                val state = viewModel.state
                val previousState = viewModel.previousState
                val buttonSpacing = 10.dp
                val isDarkTheme = isSystemInDarkTheme()
                val colors = if (isDarkTheme) DarkThemeColors else LightThemeColors
                CalculatorApp(
                    state = viewModel.state,
                    previousState = viewModel.previousState,
                    buttonSpacing = buttonSpacing,
                    colors = colors,
                    viewModel = viewModel
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CalculatorApp(
    state: CalculatorState,
    previousState: CalculatorState,
    buttonSpacing: Dp,
    colors: Color,
    viewModel: CalculatorViewModel
) {}
```

This is the top level declaration of my code to change the UI theme between dark and night.\

```
object DarkThemeColors {
    val number_buttons = Color(0xFF98c1d9)
    val top_row_buttons = Color(0xFF3d5a80)
    val background =  Color(0xFF293241)
    val operation_buttons = Color(0xFFee6c4d)
}

object LightThemeColors {
    val number_buttons = Color(0xFFf5ebe0)
    val top_row_buttons = Color(0xFFd5bdaf)
    val background =  Color(0xFFedede9)
    val operation_buttons = Color(0xFFd6ccc2)
}
```

This is my Color.kt file where I made to objects. Why am I getting this error? Please help

I am trying to have two color themes for Dark and Night however the the colors is showing a Type Mismatch and isn't importing the colors from the Color.kt file

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend that you edit your question so that your `import` statements are visible in your source code. There are multiple `Color` types; you may be using the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the type inferred in Android Studio.

[image]

We can see here that the `colors` type is inferred as `Any`.

You have created two custom objects `DarkThemeColors` and `LightThemeColors`.
Hence `Any` is inferred as the type.

[Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/)

> Every Kotlin class has Any as a superclass

To create dark and light color themes you can use `darkColors()` and `lightColors()` from Material Design.

Answer (score 1):

I think your want to use your custom color in your app. for this you can use below code and use any color as you want.

**Steps 1:**
You want to create one data class inside your Theme.kt

**Example :**

```
    @Immutable
    data class CustomColorsPalette(
    val bottomSheetColor: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    val textColor: Color = Color.Unspecified)
```

**Step 2**
Create a variable below data class. and create 2 variable that hold over create data class value for light and dark.

**Example :**

```
  val LocalCustomColorsPalette = staticCompositionLocalOf { CustomColorsPalette() }
```

Custom color (ligth/dark) variable.

```
val OnLightCustomColorsPalette = CustomColorsPalette(
    bottomSheetColor = White,
    backGroundColor = White)

val OnDarkCustomColorsPalette = CustomColorsPalette(
    bottomSheetColor = Black,
    backGroundColor = Black)
```

and last step to setup all the think in theme. and all the above point's are below in side theme class.
[image]

**And now when ever you want to use your custom color in your app you can use like this:**

```
   @Composable
   fun test() {
    Text(text = "Hanif", color = LocalCustomColorsPalette.current.textColor)
}
```